# How to find perfect squares for different values of a variable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Consider $x^2-x-a=0$, I want to find value of a for which the roots of the equation are integers $ ∀$ $ a∈ℕ $ and $a≤100$.

So the discriminant should be a perfect square.

So $1+4a=k^2$ Now I have to find all possible values of $a$.

I proceeded like this:

$4a=k^2 -1=(k+1)(k-1)$

Now When I tried to solve by breaking $4a$ into $4 · a$ and $2 · 2a$ and $4a · 1$. I could find only $2$ solutions. However there are more than that like $12$, $20$, etc.

I found the values by putting value of a and found difference between consecutive terms to be in A.P. but still couldn't figure out the general form.

How do I find them without putting values of $a$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Notice if we ensure $k\ge 2$ is odd, then $$a=\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{4} $$ will be a natural number, as we get atleast one factor of $2$ each from $k-1$ and $k+1$.

Comment: equality doesn't hold true and thanks for the hint

Comment: @YashasvPrajapati What do you mean?

Comment: Equality of k=2 doesn't make 'a' natural number

Comment: @YashasvPrajapati True, but any *odd* value of $k\ge2$ does, $k\ge 2$ doesn’t necessarily mean $k=2$.

Comment: Yeah I got it, I didn't think in that direction, thanks.

Comment: @YashasvPrajapati You’re welcome!